# Is there any difference in the expressiveness of boolean grammars versus definite clause grammars?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, prolog

[Definite clause grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) have been around a long time and are included in logic languages such as Prolog.

They can be translated into (are just syntactic sugar for) Prolog programs and are therefore I assume turing complete (unless I have missed an important limitation of DCGs relative to full Prolog).

Prolog is a logic programming language and of course supports the Boolean operators.

[Boolean grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_grammar) were introduced much more recently and are typically described as an *advance* on previous approaches.
It is not immediately obvious why they might be more expressive than DCGs.

Don't both DCGs and Boolean grammars come down to expressing linguistic rewrite rules as:

```
  LHS(attributes...) -> RHS1(attributes...) [<boolean operator> RHS2(attributes)]*
```

E.g.

```
  S -> NP VP | 
       S V O | 
       foo & bar & not Z
```

What are the limitations of DCGs?

How do Boolean grammars differ?

I think Boolean grammars don't make use of attributes. That ought to make them less expressive rather than more. I see no reason why you shouldn't use attributes with Boolean grammars in principle however.

I should clarify what I mean by expressive. I mean it in both senses:

- Is the set of languages that can be parsed using one bigger or different than the other
  &
- Does the written formalism express a language more compactly and intuitively

Though those are really different questions.