# what are the limitations of definite clause grammars?

Tags: parsers, prolog

Definite clause grammars have been around for a long time but there are not the answer to every parsing problem or we would not need to invent new formalisms. **Are there any languages they cannot express in principle?**

Why are they not used more?

https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node10.html
partially answers the second question but not the first.

> Prolog execution of the underlying deterministic machines and its use
>   of a stack to schedule them naturally yields a recursive descent
>   parser. And it is well known that a recursive descent parser cannot
>   handle left-recursive grammars; it will go into an infinite loop on
>   them. So in Prolog we must avoid left-recursive grammars.
>
> Also a recursive descent parser can be quite inefficient on some
>   grammars, because it may re-parse the same substring many times. In
>   fact, there are grammars for which recursive descent parsers take time
>   exponential in the length of the input string. When using DCGs in
>   Prolog, the programmer must be aware of these limitations and program
>   around them. It is for this reason that some people respond to the
>   claim that "You get a parser for free with Prolog" with "Maybe, but
>   it's not a parser I want to use."

Its not clear if its a fundamental limitation of DCGs themselves rather than just the Prolog implementation. I don't see why Prolog couldn't memoize common substrings like a chart parser (most Prolog implementations memoise already).

See also my related question [Is there any difference in the expressiveness of boolean grammars versus definite clause grammars?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/102103/75840)